# Sample of virtual memory using to work with Big Arrays

Tags: c#, c++, virtual-memory

I am dumb in C++/C# and WinAPI. Can someone share with me useful links or show simple sample of using virtual memory for working with big arrays( on C++ or on C#).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no virtual memory "in C++". I'm not an expert in C#, but I'm willing to bet that there's no virtual memory there, either.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/dynamic_memory_allocation.html

Comment: @KerrekSB: You think the memory which is allocated using, for example, `new` is *real* memory? I think, you got it wrong.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm saying that none of this is "C++"!

Comment: @KerrekSB: I didn't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Dull: There is no concept of virtual memory in C++. Virtual memory is an OS based mechanism which has nothing to do with C++ as such. Whether you are asking about dynamic memory allocations through `new` etc or you are asking about `dynamic polymorphism` is not clear.

Comment: I need to use  GetSystemInfo ,GlobalMemoryStatus,VirtualQuery etc( WIN API functions for working with Virtual Memory).I need to write test project.Earlier I wrote  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680439/virtual-memory-sample-code-winapi-c but my teacher said that is very simple and he said that my project must have define goal.

Comment: What is the defined goal of your project? That might help us help you.

Comment: Main goal is to show usage of Virtual Memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are after is using Memory Mapped Files which allows you to use the content of a file "as if" it was loaded into memory when in actuality it exists mostly on disk.

Take a look at ["Creating a File View" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for windows, or [man mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) for Linux.

Answer (score 2):

**Virtual memory is not a property of your programming language.** You cannot *ever* see virtual memory from a C++ program or a C# program. You are *certainly* not, on any modern (<20 years) hardware or operating system afforded the ability to control it directly.

**But you're always, *always* using it.**

Try the following program on your local machine:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int, const char*[])
{
    const std::size_t one_megabyte = 1024 * 1024;
    char* gigantic_array[5*1024];   // 5GB in blocks of 1MB

    std::size_t counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        // Allocate and use the memory (prevents OS cheating)
        gigantic_array[counter] = new char[one_megabyte];
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < one_megabyte; ++i)
             gigantic_array[counter][i] = 'F';

        ++counter;
        std::cout << "Allocated " << counter / 1024. << "GB of memory." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Before you run this program, run `top` in a separate shell. Now run it. You're going to very quickly see the program you just ran race to the top of the list. Numbers will be scrolling by...

Now soon, you'll probably notice a pause. On my laptop, that happened at 1.3 GB, more or less. At this pause, you're out of physical memory on your machine and virtual memory starts swapping things out to disk. Again, you didn't just *turn on* virtual memory, you only made its job harder by actually making it evict things from RAM.

Now wait. How much RAM do you have on your machine? I have 4GB here. I killed the program *by hand* after it had allocated 5.5GB of memory. Again, you never "turn it on". It's a basic function of the operating system that your program can't easily tell how much *physical* memory it's using.

So I hope I've convinced you to look at virtual memory a little differently. Hopefully that helps you get on with your big array problem, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know iam necroing this Q but it has no selected answer.
Since virtual Memory is always and everywhere, you cant forgo using it.
You can however control it more directly see the msdn for c# memorypages, or you can create a file and use it as buffer ("fileview"), check for exception and off you go, (with the help of a little serialization of your objects)

or, the more elegant way in my opinion:
unsafe Code =) 
create an array each cell in that array holds a ref to an array that holds that sector of your big-picture array.

(With a little system magic you can calculate a good size for your part array -> get the size of 1 chunk of your filesystem, that way no space is lost.) if you trust your OS you can just take a typical base 2 number for size.